# Why use multiple partitions on Linux installations?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

Does it really perform better than a single partitioned installation?

Why?

Comment: No. Unless you are running crazy high-demand servers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even if the performance increase is non-existent, there are several reasons to split up your installation:

- If one file system corrupts, the rest of your data is intact
- A process gone (i. e. writing excessive log files) only fills one partition
- You can mount your /home directory in several installations

etc.

Wikipedia has a great summary on the [benefits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Benefits_of_multiple_partitions) of multiple partitions.

Answer (score 11):

Multiple partitions are helpful when you want to upgrade your distribution, change to another distribution etc, especially a separate "/home" partition. All your data resides on the /home partition, so its very easy to reinstall a distribution without losing any of your data.

More info here - http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lx-partition.html

Answer (score 3):

I mainly use the multiple partition for a couple of reasons:

- Upgrading or changing distros is easier. Having your /home partition gives you the peace of mind that you can always easily backup (to a /media/Data) and start the upgrade.
- Backup protection, just in case a file system gets screwed, you have only limited loss.
- OS information is separated from my data files which is beneficial for organization and loss prevention. If my OS partition gets corrupted, I can easily reinstall the OS.
- Multi-boot